# S&P 500 VFAIX (Mutual Fund) vs VOO (ETF)?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, roth-ira, etf

I currently have just under $10,000 in a Vanguard Roth IRA brokerage account. So far I have purchased VOO ETFs since they have a lower expense ratio than VFINX. My next contribution will put me over $10,000 allowing me to purchase VFIAX. I am trying to decide whether it is worth it to convert over my VOO shares to VFAIX shares. My thoughts so far:

Both have exactly the same expense ratio 0.04% and should have almost exactly the same performance since they track the same index.

VOO

Pros:

- Already purchased/selling could be taxed (not sure if this applies with Roth IRA)

Cons:

- No automatic investment
- Have to buy whole shares (some dollar amount left over)
- Trading fees and commissions (not applicable since trading Vanguard ETFs is free with Vanguard account)
- Possibly risky due to liquidation (unlikely with ETF as big as VOO)

VFIAX:

Pros:

- Automatic investment
- Can invest all of my money (don't have to buy whole shares)

Cons:

- Possibly tax considerations (not sure if this applies with Roth IRA)

Are there any other major considerations I have left out? Also, are my assumptions in the list correct?

Comment: Trading fees are often higher for mutual funds than for the equivalent ETF (as you note, this doesn't apply when held in an account directly with the manager, only in a third-party brokerage account)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no taxes on transactions within an IRA (Traditional or Roth), so that's not something you need to consider. However, there are four other details I can think of that you should keep in mind:

- ETFs can be traded like stocks, with buy/sell market/limit/etc. orders at any point during trading hours. Mutual funds have their values recalculated only once a day, after market close, and all transactions for the day occur at that price. This could be a pro or con depending on your point of view—maybe you could save a few cents with a limit order; on the other hand, VFIAX may be less stressful in that respect as you don't even need to decide if you want a market or limit order (and what price).
- Most Vanguard mutual funds, including VFIAX, have frequent-trading restrictions. That means if you sell some VFIAX, [you can't (easily) buy more of it for 30 days](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/whatweoffer/overview/redemptionpolicy). [There are ways around that restriction, however](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Frequent_trading_policy). ETFs do not have this limit. This policy is unlikely to affect you, but it's something to be aware of.
- Some mutual funds are subject to [purchase and/or redemption fees](https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/fees). That means you will be charged to put money in or take money out. VFIAX doesn't have fund-specific fees, but [Vanguard says](https://personal.vanguard.com/pdf/vbsfreq.pdf) "for no-transaction-fee funds, Vanguard Brokerage Services imposes a $50 redemption fee for all sales
  within 60 calendar days of the trade date of the most recent purchase." I interpret that as applying to VFIAX, so you'll want to be aware of that as well.