# Why do some Vanguard Admiral Shares have higher expense ratios?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, vanguard, expense-ratio

My understanding of Vanguard "Admiral Funds" is that they charge lower management fees (have lower expense ratios) in exchange for there being a minimum investment amount.

However, it seems that currently in some cases the Admiral Funds version of a fund actually has a *higher* expense ratio than its investment fund counterpart. For example, [Vanguard 500 Index Fund Admiral Shares](https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/profile/vfiax) (VFIAX) has an expense ratio of 0.04% whereas [Vanguard S&P 500 ETF](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/voo) (VOO) has an expense ratio of 0.03%. The former is a mutual fund and the latter is an ETF. But, the only real other difference between the two as far as I can tell is the $3000 minimum investment needed for the former.

So, what am I missing? With the current expense ratios why would one ever want to buy VFIAX over VOO? (Note: from [here](https://fourpillarfreedom.com/voo-vs-vfiax-whats-the-difference/) it looks like they used to have the same expense ratio.)

Comment: Follow-up: [This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/96791/sp-500-vfaix-mutual-fund-vs-voo-etf?rq=1) is related, but just focuses on the ETF vs. mutual fund aspect. I'm wondering if there's another difference.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't think the mutual fund/ETF difference is sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

At one time for the individual investor, there were two types of each fund.

- A low cost mutual fund.
- An even lower cost Admiral shares version of the fund with a higher minimum.

When I started investing in their funds, your needed $10,000 in the fund to be upgraded to Admiral shares. The biggest difference besides the higher minimum is that you had a lower expense ratio.

Eventually a 3rd option was created, an ETF.

A few years ago the two mutual fund options were consolidated. Now The admiral shares have a much lower minimum of $3,000.

> With the current expense ratios why would one ever want to buy VFIAX
> over VOO?

It depends. Do you want an ETF or a mutual fund. I prefer mutual funds. I don't trade funds. I have re-balanced over the years. I have sold and bought shares when I left companies and moved the investments from a 401(k) into IRAs. I have purchased more shares over the years. I have reinvested my dividends. Never once have I had to buy or sell an integer number of shares.

If I have $1,000,000 in the S&P 500 fund, the annual difference in the two expenses rations is:

```
 0.04% x $1,000,000 or $400
```

vs.

```
 0.03% x $1,000,000 or $300
```

for a delta of $100.